# invoke virtual method 'void androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)'on null obj reference

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to display two fragments with BottomNaviagtionView one is HomeFragment and second is AboutFragment. 1st one is Ho and 2nd mefragment which also has tablayout and contains two fragments which is working properly.
But now I want 2 only main fragments from bottomNavigationview 1st HomeFragment and 2nd Aboutfragment.

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
FloatingActionButton add;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager2 viewPager2;
MyAdapter myAdapter;
public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    add = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    tabLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager2 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
    viewPager2.setAdapter(myAdapter);//this is where error occured
     //Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
    add.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), AddMesurement.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    });
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
    viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
}
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
tools:context=".HomeFragment">

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_note_add_24"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_200"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recent"
        android:text="RECENT"/>
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/confirmed"
        android:text="CONFIRMED"/>

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

//this is my main java file which is having bottom bar and I am accessing fregments from this file.
**Homepage.java**

```
 public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);
    fragmentReplace(new HomeFragment());
    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case (R.id.home):
                    fragmentReplace(new HomeFragment());
                    break;
                case (R.id.about):
                    fragmentReplace(new AboutFragment());
                    break;
                default:
                    fragmentReplace(new HomeFragment());
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
private void fragmentReplace(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

Comment: You're calling findViewById 1) on the activity, not the fragment, 2) before you inflate the fragment's view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
                add = v.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
                tabLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
                viewPager2 = v.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
                myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
                viewPager2.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                add.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), AddMesurement.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                });
                tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        viewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    }
                });
                viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        super.onPageSelected(position);
                        tabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();
                    }
                });
                return v; }
```

Just add some syntatic sugar cause this editor didn't paste the code very well.

Comment: if possible can you elaborate more because I am beginner and I didn't get what you've answered.